# Throwing error during arithmetic overload

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, try-catch

I am implementing a Swift 3 class that supports arithmetic operator overloading. I want the division (/) operation to throw an error if divisor is zero. Also multiply (*) to throw if an overflow will occur.

This requires me to use try with my in-line arithmetic.

```
var x = try a / b
```

That's OK except **try** is only required when the calculation uses an object of my class. This is awkward, inconsistent coding.

The alternative is to build the integrity checks outside each calculation, which is duplicative and vulnerable to coding error/omissions.

**What is good/better/best practice in Swift to try/throw/catch errors within operator-overloaded expressions?**

Comment: May be you could return a nil if something went wrong instead of throwing an exception. So the return type would be an optional

Comment: I experimented with nil. It didn't seem to be the pattern for other operator overloads, though I didn't dig too deeply. Also, I think the syntax would become elaborate in compound statements. Do you think nil is better than try/catch?

Comment: You are right, I also feel throwing exception for common operations is a bit of an overkill. Yes it is possible to have division by zero error. Similarly it is possible to access an array with an out of bound index. Completely trying to eliminate runtime errors might prove too cumbersome for normal programming unless you really have lots of these issues